# Добавлять значения объекту

Tags: java, android, объекты

Допустим я в своем классе обращаюсь к модели, в которой содержаться какие то данные.
После того как я обратился к конкретной переменной скажем, я хочу методом `.add();` добавить эти значения в объект.
Что делать если мне нужно добавить несколько значений объекту?
Придётся создавать несколько раз `.add();`, обращаясь каждый раз к `get/set'ру` в модели?

Возможно вопрос не совсем корректно сформулирован, заранее извиняюсь а также открыт для любых поправок.

Comment: какие типы данных вы добавляете ?

Comment: в цикле проитерируйтесь вызывая метод add, или создайте метод addAll(Collection<T>data). Если методы разные то никак, придется каждый раз вызывать, или создать метод  принимающий коллекцию значений и вызывающий эти самые методы

Answer (score 7):

Можно написать такой метод:

```
public void add(String... strings){
    list.addAll(Arrays.asList(strings)); //например добавить всё в лист
}
```

И давать методу хоть сколько аргументов через запятую